# How to say we failed to reach an agreement

Tags: translation

How do I convey that two parties were unable to come to terms on a given issue?

For example in English we can say this in a variety of different ways:

```
We failed to reach an agreement on plans for dinner.

We were unable to finalize the decision on how many employees to lay off

We were unable to come to terms on how to split the profit.

We could not agree on how to proceed with this issue.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try 未能， 无法， 不能，失败 for 'failed', always depends on the context. 'reach an agreement' will also translate in various ways.

We failed to reach an agreement on our plans for the annual dinner.
我们未能就年度晚宴的计划

未能 ... 达成协议。
not can ... arrive become agreement

We were unable to finalize the decision on how many employees to lay off.
我们未能就裁员多少人的问题作出最后决定。

未能...作出最后决定
not can... hammer out a decision

We were unable to come to terms on how to split the profit.
我们无法就如何分配利润达成协议。

We could not agree on how to proceed with this issue.
我们不能就如何处理这一问题达成协议。

Answer (score 1):

failed to reach an agreement
--for bussiness,we say"无法达成共识" or "协商失败"
--for daliy life ,we say"说不通” or“沟通失败”

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for an idiom, see 不欢而散.

Answer (score 0):

formal

未能/没能就...达成协议。

未能/没能在...的问题上达成/得到共识.

casual

没能说到一起去

意见没有得到统一